# Getting a Row in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble getting another row from my table. I'm trying to get it to echo the ID column for the result in my table. I think I'm missing something really simple...

```
//-select the database to use
$mydb=mysql_select_db("TABLE");

//-query the database table
$sql="select * from Contacts where `Email`= $email_user";

//-run the query against the mysql query function
$result=mysql_query($sql);

//-if Email and email_user are the same if will echo the ID
if ($result=$name_user){
echo "Hello your ID is " $ID;
}
else{
    echo "Sorry we could find that user";
}
?>
```

Comment: Read the documentation for `mysql_query()` it will return a resource, that you then can use with `mysql_fetch_row()` and so on. `$result = mysql_query($sql); if($result) { $row = mysql_fetch_row($result); }`, also like @Dagon stated, you need to quote `$email_user` if it's a string.

Comment: unlikley that you query is correct unless `$email_user` is an interger

Comment: and please use `mysqli` not `mysql` extension

Comment: And generally, `$result=$name_user` is not the same operation as `$result==$name_user`. It will return whatever `$result` receives every time, as it's an assignment. And, just so you know, your code is vulnerable to SQL-injection (unless you validate `$email_user`).

Comment: `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications and will be removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember, that mysql_query returns query resource handler, not result.

You must call mysql_fetch_assoc($queryResource) to get the results.

In your example:

```
//-select the database to use
$mydb=mysql_select_db("TABLE");

//-query the database table
$sql="select * from Contacts where `Email`= '$email_user'";

//-run the query against the mysql query function
$queryResource=mysql_query($sql);
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryResource);

if ($result){
    echo "Hello your ID is ". $result['Id'];
}
else{
    echo "Sorry we could find that user";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will need to quote your `$email_user` variable if this is a string:

```
$sql="select * from Contacts where `Email`= '$email_user'";
```

Then you should read the [documenation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) for `mysql_query()` which will tell you
that in the case of a `SELECT` query the result can be a resource that you then will
pass to a function like `mysql_fetch_array()`, `mysql_fetch_assoc()` and so on, in order to get the actual data.

One last thing, don't use the old and deprecated `mysql` extension, you should really switch to `mysqli` or `pdo`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains many errors.

- email is not an integer but a string; it has to be put in quotes.
- you can't directly compare `$result` with `$name_user`.

**CORRECTED CODE**

```
$sql="select * from Contacts where `Email`= '$email_user'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$user_found = 0; // will be set to 1 if user is found otherwise 0

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

   if ($row['name_user'] == $name_user) {
      $user_found = 1;
      echo "Hello your ID is " . $row['ID'];
      break;
   }
}

if($user_found == 0) {
   echo "Sorry we could find that user";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `mysql_fetch_array` or `mysql_fetch_assoc`

```
   <?
    //-select the database to use
    $mydb = mysql_select_db("TABLE");

    //-query the database table
    $sql = "select * from Contacts where `Email`= $email_user";

    //-run the query against the mysql query function
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    //-if Email and email_user are the same if will echo the ID
    if ($row['Email'] == $name_user){
    echo "Hello your ID is " $row['ID'];
    }
    else{
        echo "Sorry we could find that user";
    }
    ?>
```